# Получение ассоциативного массива/мэпа через Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть 2 динамических формы:

```
<div class="yesterday">
        <h3>Enter yesterday URL's and code</h3>
        <p @click="addNewRow(yedIndexes)" class="addnew">Add URL/code form</p>
        <div 
            class="row"
            v-for="row in yedIndexes"
            >
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="linkurl" placeholder="Enter link">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="linkcode" placeholder="Enter HTML code">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="today">
        <h3>Enter today URL's and code</h3>
        <p @click="addNewRow(todIndexes)" class="addnew">Add URL/code form</p>
        <div 
            class="row"
            v-for="row in todIndexes"
            >
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="linkurl" placeholder="Enter link">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="linkcode" placeholder="Enter HTML code">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Мне нужно через `Vue` (если это возможно) загнать эти данные в ассоциативный массив (а в идеале в стандартный `JS` `map`, если это возможно).
Пример `JSON`:

`[{key:'key1, value: 'value1''},{key:'key2, value: 'value2''},{key:'key3, value: 'value3''}]`

Не понимаю с какой стороны подойти для реализации. И хотелось бы узнать, валидно ли такое представление данных:

```
var todayMap = new Map();

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data:{
        todayLinks: todayMap
   },
   methods:{
        addNewRow: function(day){
            day.push('');
        }
   }
})
```

Comment: Пример данных в студию.

Comment: @doox911 на данный момент банально сравниваются строки. Условно вводится : 'key1', 'value1, 'key2', 'value2', 'key3', 'value3' /map[{key:'key1, value: 'value1''},{key:'key2, value: 'value2''},{key:'key3, value: 'value3''}]. Мне нужно, чтобы они попадали в мэп всегда парами, независимо от того, в каком порядке они вводятся

Comment: Для помощи, поместите это в вопрос и отформатируйте.

Comment: А для чего использовать `new Map()`? Тут ведь нужен обычный массив объектов. И почему при инициализации у вас не описаны модели в поле `data`: `yedIndexes`и `todIndexes`. Зато описана модель `todayLinks`, но нигде не используется?